# Hibernate can't find the persistence.xml file

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

my programm can't find the configuration file (persistence.xml). Can someone help me? I already tried to put the file in the same folder as "PersonDAO.java".
Stacktrace:
[Stacktrace and DAO sourcecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiOM5.png)
Project structure:
[Project strucutre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU0ka.png)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are building, but if you have `resource` or `resources` folder, put it in:

`resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`

That is the normal convention to get file bundled in your `JAR`.  If you go against the convention, you will most likely have to modify your build script to include it.

That is also where `JPA` looks for it (jar/META-INF/persistence.xml)

If you put in the same folder as `PersonDAO.java`, you will have to instruct your build system to copy it to the conventional location, because even if `xml` files from the source directory are included in the `jar`, they will still be in the package directory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Project Structure snapshot, resources/META-INF/persistence.xml is the correct location.

Please verify the jar, if the file exists in the packaged jar. If not verify your maven configuration.

Please share the error log, if not successful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the META-INF folder was in the wrong directory, the folder was under WebContent and it should be under SRC.
[DIRECTORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eoEp.png)
Thank you and I wish you all a good day.
Kind regards
Nikola

Answer (score 0):

The META-INF folder must be in the src folder